# CP Tensor Decomposition and Correlating Sample Magnitudes with Variables of Interest

Tags: matrix, matrix-decomposition, tensor

I am learning about tensor decomposition, specifically CP, and am trying to understand if I can use it for my research.

To give a bit more detail, I have brain imaging data from 10 participants, with each participant having data of 50 (brain regions) x 500 (time series of each brain region).

Accordingly, I have a 10 x 50 x 500 tensor, which I can submit to CP for tensor decomposition to find underlying components.

However, I now want to study how these components relate to behaviour. The same participants have neuropsychological data collected (e.g. memory performance).

My question is, if I am interested in incorporating behaviour, how can I do so in a CP framework? Would I use the resulting "subject" mode of the resulting component (which would have 10 values, one for each subject) and correlate those with my variable of interest? Or would I add an extra dimension to the tensor initially of my behaviour variable, and then submit the now 4-way tensor for decomposition?

I know I'm not understanding that well, so any thoughts/insight would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I've come across a few papers now in which each participant's weight (for a given component) are correlated with another variable of interest. Is this okay to do?

Comment: Are the behaviors categorical variables?